# Is there a way to indent a block of yaml code in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, yaml

If I made a tiny mistake at the beginning part of a yaml file and couldn't spot this until up to the completion of this file, imagine the workload of manually spacing each line after the mistake?

Answer (score 0):

On VS you can format the whole document by pressing Shift+Alt+F,or if you want to just format a selection Ctrl+K, Ctrl+F.

If you have Vscode shortcuts enabled you can select a portion of code and use Ctrl+[ to indent outward and Ctrl+] to indent inward.

You can also use the UI.

First Navigate to the Edit tab on the menu bar.

[image: VS menu bar]

Then select advanced options under there.

[image: Edit > Advanced]

Comment: Nah, this only works for .cs files.